# Differences in world generation between minecraft platforms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console, version-differences

Within some version of Minecraft for PC I've found through web searches that the world generation differs, but my questions is rather if the main engine for world generator are the same or similar for the different platforms.

That is, does world generation differ between the PC version, the pocket edition version and/or the XBox/PS4 version? Or does all world generators use the same base algorithm?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB, I'm looking for online map viewers based on seeds, but seem to only find PC versions, and I want to verify that they are not valid for pocket edition (or other platforms).

Comment: From experience, I believe that some versions of Minecraft itself also change the algorithm.  For example, you get a different world on version x to version y.  At least, that is what I found with the Xbox 360 release of the game.

Answer (score 3):

**Between Platforms**

Between platforms there currently isn't any parity unless you consider Minecraft PE and Minecraft Windows 10 Edition to be different versions. Under Microsoft's watch, the new trend is definitely toward parity between all versions. This is the impetous for moving away from Java and moving to a single language that they are implementing across platforms. Hopefully there will be true interplay between platforms.

**Version to Version**

We've been PE tracking seeds for a long time . For most of Minecraft PE's history the world render algorithm was pretty fluid - changing a lot. But, as with the maturity of the PC platform, Pocket Edition world render has incorporated backward compatibility better in each version they have come out with. Essentially, if there is a feature in 0.13 or even 0.12, it should render and be present in 0.14, 0.15 and now even 0.16. 
Where the changes seem to lie today is when new biomes or generated structures are introduced. Seeds work the same, but with or without that specific feature or biome. Sometimes an generated structure can render in both, but have a different visual appearance due to updates.
Here's an example. We had found a seed in 0.14 that had a village right by spawn that was partially embedded or upon a mountain.

When 0.15 came out, the seed was the same, but now the village was slightly different, taking on the new Savanna Village appearance (a new addition in 0.15). Here's the comparison:

[image: Same Seed, Different Village Type]: [Savanna Village Version](https://mcpehq.com/seeds/village/cool-savanna-village-update-0-15-0/)

The seed is 'some energy' (or '988605236' numerically)

I hope that helps. The other thing that has stabilized over time is when the render engine changes. In earlier versions it would sometimes change in a point release (0.12.1 to 0.12.2) but now it seems that render engine is tuned a bit, and any changes happen at the major version level (0.12 vs 0.13).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the map generation algorithm can change per version, regardless of platform.  However, different platforms may be on different versions (for example, an update will likely occur on the PC version before the console release).

There is no guarantee that you will get the same map when generating a world on version x and version y using the same seed.

**Pocket Edition**
The pocket edition is missing features from the latest PC version, and therefore at this current time you will get different worlds from the same seed.

Source:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/seeds/324789-are-pc-seeds-the-same-as-pe-seeds

> Minecraft PE does not include all the features that the PC version has because most phones can't handle a lot of content. Therefore PE has less content making terrain generation different. If you type in the same seed on both versions the worlds will be totally different. Maybe in the distant future they will have the same terrain generation but I wouldn't count on it. Example: If you load up a PC seed that has acacia wood and use the same seed on Minecraft PE. The PE version doesn't include acacia wood yet so the wood will never generate until it is added.

---

**Console**
In terms of console comparisons, for the most part they will all be on the same version, meaning the same seed across console releases will produce the same map.

Source:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/194620-are-seeds-for-the-various-platforms-compatible

---

**PC vs Console**
Again, this depends on the version of the Console release.  However, even when in sync the console edition has some limitations (map size etc) to consider.  This will mean that the same map cannot ever be truly generated.  People have reported that most of the map may be similar (with variations around the limits of the map size and structures).

Sources:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-xbox-360-edition/mcx360-discussion/2014329-pc-seeds-on-xbox